# SteelSeries mouse not recognized as mouse on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mouse

My *SteelSeries XAI Laser Mouse* is not working on Ubuntu. It works fine under Windows, but it also interfers with booting if plugged in at startup (I don't know if this is helping, but I would assume that the bios sees it as a usb drive due to its internal memory).

If I check **xinput**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUS USB2.0 Webcam                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device   id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It seems to recognize it only as a keyboard, which is not so strange given that some featues should be programmable. The back/forward-buttons and seems not to be working though, so I'm unsure if it is a partial success at all.

The **dmesg** output gives no apparent errors:

```
[10825.417071] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[10825.512861] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1038, idProduct=1360
[10825.512873] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10825.512879] usb 2-1.2: Product: SteelSeries Gaming Device
[10825.512884] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd.
[10830.510046] input: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input25
[10830.510702] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0006: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[10835.507628] input: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/input/input26
[10835.508126] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0007: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1
[10840.503400] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0008: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.00 Device [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input2
```

The closest resemblance to an answer I've found is this derailed [thread](http://forum.novatech.co.uk/showthread.php?15532-Steelseries-Xai-on-Linux-%28Debian%29), but at least someone else seems to have had the same problem.

I have not clue how I could inform **udev** or whichever part of the system is responsible, that this mouse is actually a mouse. There's a [git repo](https://github.com/mcrapet/xaictl) for configuring a SteelSeries mouse on Ubuntu, but that seems not to be directly related either.

*So, how to get my mouse recognized as a mouse?*

**Edit**

The output of **lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1e54:2030 TypeMatrix 2030 USB Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1038:1360 Ideazon, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2885 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. ASUS Webcam
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Actually, it appears to be detecting it as *both* a keyboard and a mouse. Perhaps since the keyboard is detected last, that's what it uses... hm.... Try switching to a VT (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and showing us the relevant output of `lspci`. If you have another mouse, you might be able to open a terminal using Ctrl-Alt-T as well if that helps.

Comment: I have a touchpad so I can navigate. The relevant parts of `lsusb` seems unclear to me so I'll post it all

Comment: Actually, it's *three* HID devices. That's very weird. Hm, it might be possible to get it working just as a mouse by adding some udev rules, but then it wouldn't be fully functional either. There must be a better way. What is actual model of the mouse?

Comment: You're right that is weird. Either it's that Ideazon thing or it's not even in there. Perplexing.

Comment: That was my thought too. I have a product number 62012, but else its exact name is as I wrote at the top: XAI

Comment: D'oh! I missed that. I do a little scouring myself. I don't know if I can do anything with udev without it actually being in the list of USB devices -- which it clearly should be.

Comment: Aha! Perhaps this may help you out? http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/LLXmL9r5NAkBOViyfjZT. It appears that updating the mouse firmware might fix the issue.

Comment: After visiting the support site, I'm unsure of how exactly this would be done. Perhaps the (Windows) XAI software would do it, but I'm not sure. If that's the case it'd surely have to be done in Windows.

Comment: Though an odd solution to post here, that actually worked. Upgrading the firmware in windows (I don't know if it will work under wine) and now that mouse works. If you put it as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I highly doubt it would work in Wine, as Wine has particular issues with device mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this bug report](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/LLXmL9r5NAkBOViyfjZT), a firmware update of the mouse will fix your problems.